# How to translate strings well in Laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, translation

I want to translate product description in json. In my product.view I shows the variables.

```
<span>{{ __($product->description) }}</span>
<span>{{ __($product->beam) }}</span>
```

Here i have translation in json

```
 "Brama przesuwana wykonana na szynie jezdnej 80x80 mm. Obramowanie oraz przeciwwaga bramy wykonane są z profili 60x40 mm. Wypełnienie bramy to profil 80x20 mm w odstępach 80 mm. Istnieje możliwość wstawienia różnych kombinacji kolorystycznych wypełnienia. Słupy montażowe w komplecie - profil 80x80 mm. Brama wyposażona w niezbędne akcesoria montażowe w zależności od wersji.": "Posuvná brána je vyrobena na kolejnici 80x80 mm. Rám a protizávaží  jsou vyrobeny z profilů 60x40 mm. Brána je vyplněna profilem 80x20 mm v rozestupech 80 mm. Výplně brány je možné různě barevně kombinovat. Montážní sloupy jsou z profilů 80x80 mm. Brána je vybavena potřebným montážním příslušenstvím v závislosti na její verzi.",
   "Czarna stal Warstwa cynku Warstwa poliestru": "Černá ocel. Zinková vrstva. Polyesterová vrstva",
```

Here is the look of product page. Product beam is well translated. My question is why product description are not being translated. This happens in all my product examples.
[image: Product view]

Answer (score 0):

Here i Got It -

```
<span>{{ __(JSON.stringify($product->description)) }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert JSON to Array using below code.

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_string, TRUE);
```

Then you forEach and translate key value using below code.

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>This is user {{ __($user) }}</p>
@endforeach
```

if query feel free to ask.